# tensorflow cudnn problems (cuda 7.5, 367 driver cudnn 4) SOS

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

i am running a gtx 980ti on ubuntu 16.04, installed cuda 7.5 via deb file and cupied the cudnn files into /usr/local/cuda-7.5  ... .

I edited my bashrc file with the following:

export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-7.5 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64

PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
export PATH

Now when i run a model, i get the following :

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcublas.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2289] Unable to load cuBLAS DSO.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:2259] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcufft.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:343] Unable to load cuFFT DSO.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] Couldn't open CUDA library libcurand.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_rng.cc:333] Unable to load cuRAND DSO.
```

Does anyone see what i am doing wrong here and or knows how to fix it. All suggestions are highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You must also install the package `nvidia-cuda-dev` - this will pull in all of the other dependencies such as libcublas, libcufft and libcurand, as well as their plain `.so` symbolic links.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system, these CUDA 7.5 libraries all ended up in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` so I did not even need the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting.

Furthermore, I installed the two packages `libcudnn5_5.1.3-1+cuda7.5_amd64.deb` and `libcudnn5-dev_5.1.3-1+cuda7.5_amd64.deb` via my NVIDIA Developer account.

Now when I start ipython in a TensorFlow 0.10 configured environment, with `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD` empty, I see:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

Joy!